# problem with isometry that doesn't preserves rays, i just don't understand

Tags: self-learning, hyperbolic-geometry, axiomatic-geometry

I try to teach myself a bit of non-euclidean geometry

And I am a bit stumped by the following remark in George E. Martins "The foundations of Geometry and the Non-Euclidean Plane" page 217.
extra comments are in [ and ] i added some line breaks and my poblem is the bit in **bold**

> An isometry $\alpha $ preserves d [distance] by definition.
>
> That $\alpha $ preserves m [angle measure] means only that $ m \angle A'B'C' = m \angle ABC $.
>
> This last equation should not be misunderstood; it does not mean what it seems to mean. It is true that if $ \angle ABC $ then $ \angle A'B'C' $ and the two angles are congruent. However the equation does not say that $\alpha $ preserves angles.
>
> Even though $\alpha $ preserves betweenness, it is just not clear that $\alpha $ preserves rays or lines. **(the function  $ f $ given by $ f(x) = e^x $ preserves betweenness on the real line but does not preserves rays on the real line.)** The problem is that we do not yet know if $\alpha $ is a surjection on the points.

I can just not get my head rount the bold statement, can anybody help me?

Comment: I like Martin's book. Unusually good on constructions, compass and straightedge, including the hyperbolic plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part says that if $b$ is between $a$ and $c$ then $f(b)$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(c)$.

Now the reason why $f(x)$ does't preserves rays is because it takes the ray $(-\infty, 0]$ into $(0,1]$ which is not a ray.